# Giving an input a default value in redux-form

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, redux-form

I would have thought this is stupidly easy... but I am struggling :D

```
    <Field type="text" component="input" value="jamie" name="email" placeholder="Enter email address"/>
    <Field type="text" component="input" defaultValue="jamie" name="email" placeholder="Enter email address"/>
    <Field type="text" component="input" format="jamie" name="email" placeholder="Enter email address"/>
```

I just can't get one in there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

define `initialValues`  outSide of your class

```
const initialValues = {
  email: 'example@gmail.com'
}
```

and put initialValues here

```
export default reduxForm({
  form: 'venues',  // a unique identifier for this form
  destroyOnUnmount: true,
  validate,
  initialValue
})(VenueComponent)
```

Comment: Ah very nice! Thanks bud. Now I just need to work out how to get the values from the props

Comment: @JamieHutber Hey did u find out how to do this ?